# Best way to run .sh with elevated permissions? No password input! [APPLE SCRIPT Automation]

Tags: automation, applescript

I am using the run command as admin and I want to automate the execution of my .sh file. When I run the script as admin the SecuirtyAgent asks for my password. I wrote lines so the script brings the "SecurityAgent" front and in-puts the password but unfortunately the script pauses until the password has been entered. so I cannot automate the input of the password. Also I cannot use `do shell script "command" user name "me" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges` because this script is meant to run on different computers with different users BUT same password.

```
tell application "Finder" to set myFolder to POSIX path of (container of (path to me) as text)
do shell script quoted form of (myFolder & "ST_GLE_MAC_EES.sh") with administrator privileges

tell application "System Events"
    activate "SecurityAgent"
    tell process "SecurityAgent"
        delay 1
        set frontmost to true
        set visible to true
        set value of text field "Password:" of window 1 to "iamatitan*"
        delay 1
        click button "OK" of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

[Image of POP UP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4TIx.png)

Comment: RE" "Also I cannot use `do shell script "command" user name "me" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges` because this script is meant to run on different computers with different users BUT same password."  ... If the password is the same then why can't you use e.g. `set userName to short user name of (system info)` followed by `do shell script "command" user name userName password "iamatitan*" with administrator privileges` then `userName` is the `short user name` of the logged in user, however this only works if the logged in user is an Admin account.

Comment: @user3439894 before I try your idea I tried running my script as follows ``` tell application "Finder" to set myFolder to POSIX path of (container of (path to me) as text) do shell script quoted form of (myFolder & "ST_GLE_MAC_EES.sh") user name "hb" mepassword "mypassword" with administrator privileges ``` and I received an error "/bin/sh: /Users/hb/Desktop/MacSoft/ST_GLE_MAC_EES.sh: Operation not permitted" I believe this might be due to the System Integrity Protection on Macs. How can I run this script and automate the password input or avoid password input it all together?

Comment: OK it turns out this may be a known issue: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/catalina-and-applescript.2198111/

Comment: @matt Yes as I suspected, it is from system integrity protection... Guess it is what it is.